# Replace div contents javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript

Every time a selection is made from a dropdown menu, specific data is pulled from facebook and added to different divs. I am trying to update the contents of the div every time a different selection is made, however at the minute, the contents are just appended on after the initial contents.

This is the code that gets data based on a selection and creates the list from the returned data

```
   <script> 

    city = document.getElementById("citySelection")
    city.addEventListener("change", function() {
      var selected = this.value;
      var eventsList = document.getElementById("events");
      if (selected == "None") {
        eventsList.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        eventsList.style.display = "block";
      };
      if (selected == 'Bristol') {
        getBristolEvents();
      };
      if (selected == 'Leeds') {
        getLeedsEvents();
      };
      if (selected == 'Manchester') {
        getManchesterEvents();
      };
      if (selected == 'Newcastle') {
        getNewcastleEvents();
      };
    });


    function createList(response, listId) {
      var list = document.createElement('UL')
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var events = response.data[i].name
        var node = document.createElement('LI');
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(events);
        node.appendChild(textNode);
        list.appendChild(node)
        listId.appendChild(list);
     }};

   </script
```

This is the div being targeted:

```
<html>
 <div id="events" style="display: none">
     <div id="eventsDiv"  style="display: block">
      <div id="eventsListOne">
        <h3 id='headerOne'></h3>
     </div>
      <div id="eventsListTwo">
        <h3 id='headerTwo'></h3>
      </div>
      <div id="eventsListThree">
        <h3 id='headerThree'></h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</html>
```

I have tried resetting the innerHtml of the div every time the function to get the data from facebook is called:

```
   <script>
    function getEventsThree(fbUrl, title) {
     var listId = document.getElementById('eventsListThree');
     var headerThree = document.getElementById('headerThree');
     listId.innerHtml = "";
     headerThree.append(title)
     FB.api(
       fbUrl,
       'GET', {
         access_token
       },
       function(response) {
         listId.innerHtml = createList(response, listId)
       }
     )};
   </script>
```

However, that still doesn't reset the contents of the div.

I've looked at other response but they all use jquery which I am not using.

Can anyone advise on the best way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It would be much easier to take a look at this if it were a js snippet instead of just a text block.  It's a great SO feature and I recommend you use it whenever possible.  While you're at it, try to use more descriptive language than "doesn't work".  I'm going to offer up an answer, but it would be easy to verify if you had provided a snippet and better descriptions of error cases.

Comment: Apologies, first time posting here.

Comment: No worries friend, it's advice for your benefit.  Being able to jump into a snippet and make a quick change gives us the opportunity to provide a verifiable answer, which is likely to increase the quality of your answers.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: @Kaddath Sorry if I'm being stupid, but I'm still new to JS and coding in general. If I want to create the HTML elements then append using appendChild, how do I ensure the div is empty before the function runs?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Hennessy approach is fine.  Generate the inner content, then set `.innerHTML`.

At least one of your problems, maybe the only one, appears to be that you set `.innerHTML` to the return value of `createList`, but that function does not return anything.

Comment: Hennessy approach?

I'm sorry still a little confused.

I'm still not getting the correct functionality If I set `createList` to return the list it creates, and set `innerHTML` of `listId` to this value.

Comment: Never mind I've done it.

Setting the header and then setting innerHTML to empty was stopping interfering with the rest of the code, as my code was still trying to append the header to an element that didn't exist anymore.